# Companies VS Clients

Tags: working-from-home

So let me tell my backstory. After graduating college, a few months after, I found a work-from-home job through Craigslist. It was my first ever job. It paid $15/hr and I was supposed to get about 20 hours a week. Things went well for the first year.

In that time I was able to find another job that was basically the same (working from home) but they were paying me $20/hr. Fast forward and the "manager" from the first company leaves because the owner can't really afford him anymore. After he left things started going downhill.

Around my 1-year mark I asked for a raise and even told him I had another job that paid $20/hr. He was pretty miffed by it but raised my pay to $18/hr but pretty much told me I wouldn't get a raise for a long time.

Over the last year though I have gotten barely any hours, maybe 1 or 2 a week. He also NEVER pays me on time, which has always been twice a month on two certain days. I'm usually left begging for my pay and continually emailing. Several times I have waited a month for my paycheck.

Company B that does pay $20/hr is ran by a much nicer owner who does pay me on time, but the hours are horrible too and I can barely make $60 in a month.

I'm a freelance web designer and since my first job, things have been picking up for myself client-wise. For 2016 I'm rebranding myself and really focusing on my business. My rate with my clients is $40/hr but I really don't have enough clients to completely quit the company jobs, but I feel like I'm not being respected by the owner and not getting enough hours to even care.

I'm basically asking for advice. Do I quit those jobs and keep my pride? Or perhaps tell them that my business model has changed and my rate is $40/hr and is not negotiable? It's not like I'm working 20 hours a week anymore so if I were making $40/hr it would at least make those 1 or 2 hours worth it for me.

I also have a contract with Company A (the bad guy) but it was signed by the manager who left. It also states I will be paid twice a month, and that hasn't been met all the time, so the contract is null?

Sorry for the long post! I've been dealing with this for a while and wanted an outside perspective.

Comment: I don't think anyone here can make life decisions for you. In addition, I personally wouldn't trust a bunch of random unknown users on the internet to have any clue of the overall scope of my decision, regardless of how well i think I've typed it. Whether or not you should stay with existing employers or hope to find new ones is your decision, no one else's. Practicality would suggest one not to dump the money that *is* coming in on pure speculation that other money *may* be replacing it.

Answer (score 2):

Bridge that shiz! Here is what a bridge is. You don't raise anyone's rate but all the new business you charge at the higher rate. Honestly you could probably charge more than 40/hr but that is besides the point. Keep adding new work until you can't take on any more work. At that point you are at 100%. The next job opportunity you get, you go back to the 18/hr job and tell him you can't do work for him anymore. You quit. Don't make it awkward by asking him to match. You already know he won't. Now you will be back down to having lots of time to take on new work at a higher rate. Keep taking on new work until you are back to 100%. Now the next job opportunity you go to the 20/hr job and tell him you really like him but he needs to start paying 40/hr or you will have to stop. Meanwhile keep building your skills and charging more. If your rate goes up, keep bridging that old work! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your relation with company A depends on the content of the contract. You cannot deem it void just because of late payments.

If you can stand losing those hours, inform the guys about your new fee and the new payment conditions, including penalties for late payment.

If you don't wan't to, just warn about the penalties.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the decision completely rests upon you on which path to take.

I would suggest that you look for opportunities that utilise all the hours you have allocated to work. There are sites online as well like Upwork and PPH where you can bid for projects and work from home after being awarded with a project.

The rates you charge completely depend on your skillsets and the way in which you handle clients.

Communication is the key.
Therefore, if you want to still keep working with the companies and still have a lot of time, you should give it a thought.